# EclipseでリモートのPythonインタプリタを使いたい

Tags: python, eclipse

### 前提

EclipseでPythonを使いたくて、下記のサイトを参考にwindowsへEclipseをインストールしました。
[やってみよう分析！第8章：PythonとEclipse(PyDev)で作る分析環境 for Windows - Qiita](http://qiita.com/msano/items/e94a641274c5b7f6a75a)

---

### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

その次に pydev を Eclipse 経由でインストールして、インタプリタの設定で、 VirtualBox (CentOS7 をインストールしている) 上にインストールしてある Python をインタプリタとして指定したのですが、以下のようなエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Unable to get info onth interpreter: \\192.168.56.102\root\usr\bin\python

Common reasons include:

- Using an unsuppoted version
 (Python and Jythhn require at least version 2.1 and IronPython 2.6)

- Specifying an invaild interpreter
 (usually a link to the actual interpreter on Mac or Linux)
```

どのような手順を踏めば、リモートのインタプリタを使えるのかご教示いただきたいです。

---

### 補足情報 (OS, ツールのバージョンなど)

Eclipse
Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2)

Comment: できないと思います。pycharm + vagrantならリモートインタプリタの機能があります。

Comment: なるほど。
かしこまりました！ご教授いただきありがとうございました！